# Limit number of processed elements in Beam/Dataflow stream job

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a Beam streaming job running on Dataflow runner. It loads requests from PubSub (using Python's `apache_beam.io.ReadFromPubSub`), then fetches data from BigTable, do a heavy computation on the data and writes to PubSub again.

```
with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as pipeline:
        (
            pipeline
            | "Receive" >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(topic=TOPIC_READ)
            | "Parse" >> beam.ParDo(Parse())
            | "Fetch" >> beam.ParDo(FetchFromBigtable(project, args.bt_instance, args.bt_par, args.bt_batch))
            | "Process" >> beam.ParDo(Process())
            | "Publish" >> beam.io.WriteToPubSub(topic=TOPIC_WRITE)
        )
```

Basically I don't need any windowing, I would like just limit the number of elements processed in parallel on 1 machine (i.e. control the parallelism by number of workers). **Otherwise it causes out of memory during the heavy computation and I also need to limit the rate of BigTable requests.**

I'm using standard 2 CPU machine so I would expect that it would process 2 elemets in parallel - I also set `--number_of_worker_harness_threads=2` and `--sdk_worker_parallelism=1`. For some reason though I'm seeing many elements processed in parallel by multiple threads which cause the memory and rate limit problems. I guess those are bundles processed in parallel based on the logs (e.g. `work: "process_bundle-105"`).

[image]

I tried to hack it by using a semaphore inside `processElement` (to just process one element per DoFN instance) and it works, but the autoscaling does not kick off and it looks like a pure hack which may have other consequences.

What would you recommend? How can I limit the number of parallel bundles to be processed? Ideally just one bundle per worker harness thread? Is beam/dataflow suitable for such use case or is it better to achieve it with plain kubernetes with autoscaling?

**EDIT:**

Running on Beam SDK 2.28.0

I'd like to limit the parallelism, but I have not described well symptoms that leaded me to that conclusion.

1. Sometimes I got timeouts in the `Fetch` stage

```
Deadline of 60.0s exceeded while calling functools.partial(<bound method PartialRowsData._read_next of <google.cloud.bigtable.row_data.PartialRowsData object at 0x7f16b405ba50>>)
```

2. Processing of one element in `Process` stage slows down significantly (into minutes instead of seconds) and sometimes it even gets stuck (probably because of memory problems).

Below are logs from one worker logged before and after processing of 1 element in `Process` stage (single-threaded) filtered by `jsonPayload.worker` and `jsonPayload.portability_worker_id` (i.e. I hope those should be logs from one container). I can see much more than 12 elements being processed in a single moment.

[image: Logs of process stage]

Answer (score 2):

Dataflow launches one SDK worker container per core so in your case there will be 2 worker containers(processes) per machine. Each worker process has an unbounded thread pool for processing the bundles but I think only one bundle gets processed with one thread at a time due to python GIL.

You can `--experiments no_use_multiple_sdk_containers` to limit the sdk container number to one (since it seems that your use case does not care about throughput that much).

Comment: Thanks. Problem does not seem to be with containers though - I see only one container, but the number of threads - yeah, one bundle gets processed with one thread, but if the thread pool is unbounded it means there may be hundreds of bundles processed in parallel which kills the processing. My desire is basically limit the number of parallel bundles to 1 per one "harness thread". Btw. what `number_of_worker_harness_threads` stands for then, when I see many threads in parallel anyway?

Comment: number_of_worker_harness_threads does not have the effect of limiting threads in python sdk worker (it has the effect of limiting the threads for Dataflow runner v1 and I don't think it works for Dataflow runner v2 which python streaming job is launched with , for now). It is very uncommon to limit work parallelism for streaming job to 1 since it won't work well for majority jobs (default python streaming work parallelism is 12 * number of python sdk containers). it will require Dataflow eng team to build a customized runner v2 container to limit that parallelism for your case.

Comment: Thanks! I think that the use case for heavy processing (taking into account that Dataflow now supports GPUs) may be quite common. Would it be possible to have the `12` configurable (e.g. as an experimental option) in future releases?

Comment: I added more insights to the description. I'm seeing more than 12 threads processing in parallel. Do you think it is possible or there must be a different problem?

Comment: I created an internal feature request to add the option into future dataflow runner release.

To understand what the sdk is doing on each thread you can also ssh into the vm and do `curl localhost:8081/sdk_status`

Answer (score 1):

I have had success solving this same kind of problem for Dataflow and Elasticsearch by making use of [Stateful Processing](https://beam.apache.org/blog/stateful-processing/). You could use [GroupIntoBatches](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/python/aggregation/groupintobatches/) to reduce the parallelism if your sink cannot keep up with the pace of the rest of the pipeline.

As far as I understand, states are maintained by the runner on a per-key-per-window basis. To use stateful processing, your data will need to have keys. Those keys can be arbitrary and ignored by the DoFn you use to consume the elements.

You mentioned that you don't need windowing, and if you're not using any windowing currently that would imply that you're using the default singular Global Window. In this case, whatever number of distinct keys you arbitrarily assign to your data will be the maximum number of parallelized states maintained. Just be aware that this solution won't be portable to all runners as Stateful processing is not globally supported by all runners.